# pyinstaller does not work with with pyqt5 and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

im using pyqt5 to create a gui and using matplotlib

but whene i try to create executable with pyinstaller it dose not work

i try a few solution like :

1- [Can't create working PyQt5 Python executable with PyInstaller/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674425/cant-create-working-pyqt5-python-executable-with-pyinstaller)

2- [In PyInstaller, Why Won't NumPy.Random.Common Load as a Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264427/in-pyinstaller-why-wont-numpy-random-common-load-as-a-module)

3- [Python SSL Import Error in PyInstaller generated executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253470/python-ssl-import-error-in-pyinstaller-generated-executable)

i try to do it with cx_Freeze
and try this solution
[cx_Freeze error: baseline image directory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828976/cx-freeze-error-baseline-image-directory-does-not-exist)

but nothing work with me

this is my log after using pyinstaller

```
78 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
78 INFO: Python: 3.8.2
78 INFO: Platform: Windows-8-6.2.9200-SP0
78 INFO: wrote E:\new caissier_localhost\admin_copie\admin_admin.spec
78 INFO: UPX is not available.
78 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['E:\\new caissier_localhost\\admin_copie',
 'E:\\new caissier_localhost\\admin_copie']
93 INFO: checking Analysis
154 INFO: Building because E:\new caissier_localhost\admin_copie\admin_admin.py changed
154 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
158 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
178 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3427 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\zakaria\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3427 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\zakaria\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\lib'
7418 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7600 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7600 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
 
79139 INFO: checking PKG
79154 INFO: Building because toc changed
79154 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
123333 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
123441 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\zakaria\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
123441 INFO: checking EXE
123473 INFO: Building because toc changed
123473 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
123473 INFO: Copying icons from ['sifax.ico']
123489 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 90 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 35796 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 67624 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 16936 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 9640 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 4264 bytes
123489 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 1128 bytes
123492 INFO: Updating manifest in E:\new caissier_localhost\admin_copie\build\admin_admin\runw.exe.k_fyw9z3
123505 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
123507 INFO: Appending archive to EXE E:\new caissier_localhost\admin_copie\dist\admin_admin.exe
124030 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

is there another way to make a exe with pyinstaller that contain pyqt5 and matplotlib and Qchart

Comment: The build looks successful, so presumably your problem is when you run the exe - if you run from command prompt what is the full error message?

Comment: there is no error whene i run from terminal but the probleme is in the matplotlib packaging with pyinstaller, but after downgrade matplotlib version it work

Comment: Say you run the exe from the command prompt but in/from a different folder, what is the error message?

Comment: no error message at all the pb is with the matplotlib and the pyinstaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and downgrade your matplotlib version, which you don't seem to mention. `3.1.3` fixed it in my case using PyInstaller and PyQt5.

Comment: it work but after i downgrade PyQt to 5.15.0 thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

solved thanks to @LittleFoxyFox
and here is another way with cx_Freeze

in the import area add

```
import PIL
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
```

and change backend_qt4agg to backend_qt5aggb in

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

and create another py file with the following lignes ( in my case setup_2.py)

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "admiiiin",
    version = "0.10",
    descreption = ".....",
    executables = [Executable("admin_admin.py")]
)
```

downgrade PyQt to 5.15.0

and in the terminal

```
python setup_2.py build_exe --excludes=matplotlib.tests,numpy.random._examples
```

that will make it work but with cx_freeze